# Activity group problem in tab bar

Tags: android, tabbar, activitygroup

I have used tabbar with activity group in my application. I have four tab like home, stock, citn, article. In my application first display home page from the home page user click in webview it will go to homepage1 activity. From home page1 activity user click stock tab it will go to stock activity. From the stock activity user click home tab it will go to homepage1 activity. I want to display home activity can any body tell how to do?

My question is switching between tab using activity group it will display last activity. I want to display first activity?

ok i will attach my code

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("FirstGroup").setIndicator("FirstGroup",   
                getWallpaper()).setContent( new Intent(this,FirstGroup.class));
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

> View view =
>   getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("CitiesActivity",
>   new
>   Intent(this,CitiesActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET
>   )).getDecorView();
>
> ```
>           // Replace the view of this ActivityGroup   
>       replaceView(view);   
>
>    }   
>
> public void replaceView(View v) {   
>             // Adds the old one to history   
>     history.add(v);   
>             // Changes this Groups View to the new View.   
>     setContentView(v);
> ```

run this example 
http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/use-android-activitygroup-within-tabhost-to-show-different-activity

switching between activity and tab

I have posted in pastebin, my link is
 http://pastebin.com/1zG0HJgv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Did u tried the tabchanged event as shown below

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setContent(
                R.id.content_movies).setIndicator("",
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setContent(
                new Intent(this, Sample.class)).setIndicator("",
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_icon)));
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {


         if(arg0.equals("tab1"))
        {

       /*write the code here to show the view 
     Currentclass, the class where you have used ontabchanged function and 
     Newclass is the class where you want to navigate*/
           Intent obj_intent = new Intent(CureentClass.this,Newclass.class);
    startActivity(obj_intent);

        }

        else if (arg0.equals("tab2")) {

                 // write the code here to show the view 
       }
       //similarly for other tabs
      });
```

Comment: @user426344: what problem , you are facing, tell me friend?

Comment: @user426344: Refer the code, i had edited and convey what problem you are facing?

Comment: can u check the link ? I implemented in decorview() previous activity will be stored .your code will call new activity without tabbar

Comment: see my code above code and check this link http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/use-android-activitygroup-within-tabhost-to-show-different-activity

Comment: @hi, pls post your in pastebin.com , let me correct it my dear friend

Comment: vijayakumar: can you give that link of your pastebin.com

Comment: Hi sankar ganesh I already posted with pastebin.com  name vijayakumar

Comment: vijayakumar:pls give me a couple of seconds

Comment: can you post the answer in this site

Comment: @user @Sankar while we are all overwhelmed by the show of love and support here, I'd like to remind you both that this is StackOverflow, not PastebinOverflow, and you're denying other users searching for answers to similar problems with the working solution.  @Sankar please edit your answer and include the code you've dropped on pastebin.  Also, to everybody flagging these comments, I hope this will satisfy your concerns.

Comment: @Will: Sure, Here after, we will follow what you have commented, thanks for correcting the mistake.

Comment: @Sankar thanks, and thanks for taking the time to help others out (see, I can do the lovefest too!)